# Blazor Server: How to close browser and return a message to calling app

Tags: c#, blazor, jscript

I recently converted my ageing asp.net webforms site to Blazor server.

One page on the site is called using a WebView2 browser control hosted in a separate net5 app. The call is made so that users of the app can purchase a license. When payment is complete the browser should return the user to the app so that registration can complete.

In my original webforms code, transfer back to a method in the app was done via a simple Jscript function:

```
  Response.Write("<script>window.external.onbrowserclosed('" & exitmessage & "');</script>")
```

where onbrowserclosed is the target method in the app. and exitmessage a simple string with the results of the purchase.

I tried to rewrite this function in Blazor Server in _Host.cshtml as

```
<script>
        function closebrowser(message) {external.closebrowser.onbrowserclosed  };
</script>
```

calling it from a Razor component that handles purchasing:

```
 await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("closebrowser", exitmessage);
```

This calls the script OK, but only if the target method (onbrowserclosed) and the message parameter are removed. When called without the target method it simply closes the browser, but obviously that's not what I'm looking for. It seems window.external is not fully supported in Blazor.

Has anyone else hit this problem ? I'd prefer to find a Blazor/.Net native alternative to call back to the app. but a JScript solution would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I implemented a gRPC listener which polls my site for changes in transaction status. Not as elegant as a callback but gRPC is fast and reliable, so definitely the way to go.

If anyone hits the same issue I can provide a more detailed description.